# How to sketch the following set?

Tags: complex-numbers

Sketch on the argand's diagram the following set: $A=\{w \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}:w^3-w^{-3} \in \mathbb{R}\}$. How to approach this question?

Comment: Do you mean:
$$
A=\{w \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}:w^3-w^{-3} \color{red}{ = 0}\}?
$$

Comment: something different

Comment: Break it into steps. Let $z = w^3$, find $B = \{ z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\} : z-z^{-1}\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as follows:

Defining $w = x + iy$, find an expression for $\text{Im}[w^3 - w^{-3}]$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.  Set the result equal to $0$.

In particular, we have
$$
w^3 - w^{-3} = 
(x + iy)^3 - \frac{(x - iy)^3}{(x^2 + y^2)^3}
$$
Alternatively, defining $w = r \cos \theta + i r \sin \theta$, we have
$$
w^3 - w^{-3} = 
r^3 \cos 3 \theta + i r^3 \sin 3 \theta - \frac{\cos 3\theta - i \sin 3\theta}{r^3}
$$

---

Setting the imaginary part of the above equal to zero gives us
$$
r^3 \sin 3 \theta - r^{-3}\sin 3 \theta = 0 \implies\\
(r^6 - 1) \sin 3 \theta = 0
$$
So, the solution will be the circle $|w| = 1$, along with the lines associated with the arguments $ \pi k/ 3$ where $k \in \{0,1,\dots,6\}$.

Comment: Question what is the precise shape of the graph? Just straight line or something more?

Comment: It will be the union of several straight lines